# Android : Support in-app updates result getting cancelled

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-app-bundle, in-app-update

Implementing the **Immediate In App** Update using Google play core library.

Followed the all guidelines given in the https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates.

The issue is user clicks the update and downloading is in progress, In middle of that due to some problem **user cancels it by clicking the close button**. After that whenever i tried to Update, the onActivityResult is RESULT_CANCELED.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @FelipePereiraGarcia If you get any proper approach to solve this issue. Please help me also

Comment: There seems to a bug indeed. Please file a bug here if you want to be notified when it's fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:384531%20status:open

Answer (score 3):

I confirm that a bug was introduced in the current version of the Play Store app (which is backing the Play Core library).

The bug has been fixed and will be rolled out in the next couple of weeks.
It will NOT require a Play Core version upgrade.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Can I know is this rolled out or not?

Comment: as per the comment in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133092990 this is rolled out.